# How to sort in a other way (mysqli)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

my question as I instructions in a sql sorting can put upside down. I currently use 
`"ORDER by id DESC"` does anyone know how I can get the other way around?

This is my code:

```
"SELECT ip FROM chat WHERE datum > '".$timestamp."' GROUP BY ip ORDER BY id DESC"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
SELECT ip FROM chat WHERE datum > '".$timestamp."' GROUP BY ip  ORDER BY id ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

ASC = The default sort order is ascending, with smallest values first. To sort in reverse (descending) order, add the DESC keyword to the name of the column you are sorting by:

```
"SELECT ip FROM chat WHERE datum > '".$timestamp."' GROUP BY ip ORDER BY id ASC"
```

**[SE THE DOCUMENTER OF SORTING ROWS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/sorting-rows.html)**

Answer (score 0):

Just use

```
ORDER BY id
```

This will do in ascending order.

By default when `Order by column` its ascending. If explicitly specified as `DESC` then the ordering is done is descending order in MySql